# I couldn't MongoDB Installation on Debian

Tags: mongodb, debian

I installed mongodb from this [link](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/install-mongodb-on-debian/)

When i enter`mongo` in console I got error

```
root@512son:~# mongo
MongoDB shell version: 2.6.9
connecting to: test
2015-04-10T05:35:23.837+0000 warning: Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1:27017, reason: errno:111 Connection refused
2015-04-10T05:35:23.838+0000 Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017 (127.0.0.1), connection attempt failed at src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:146
exception: connect failed
```

I searched this problem on internet and i tried:

```
sudo rm /var/lib/mongodb/mongod.lock
mongod --repair
```

If i enter `mongod` in terminal Mongodb work fine but when i close terminal mongodb is closing

I reinstall two times but my problem not fixed

Comment: what do you mean by *if I enter `mongod` in terminal* ? why close the terminal? you can't use `mongo shell` if no `mongod` instance running.

Comment: i use mongodb on production server. terminal always turn on in my pc ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to run MongoDB in the background. I mean start  [*mongod as daemon*](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/tutorial/manage-mongodb-processes/#start-mongod-as-a-daemon) using `--fork`